# Silverlight 4, toggling visibility on different views

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is this any different than setting visibility on controls?

I have 2 different views and I would like to show one when the user clicks on a button if a certain condition is met.

Using MVVM approach if it matters at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your views are just composite controls (in that they inherit UserControl), then no - there's no difference.